# Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource with computed SHA-256 integrity

Tags: heroku, shopify, shopify-app

I am developing Shopify App, with help of Heroku server.
After hitting the URL `https://warm-tundra-19548.herokuapp.com`.
It is redirecting to login page i.e "https://prnt.sc/qcvkdc"
After adding domain i.e `https://daisylilly.myshopify.com`.

Then blank screen come with message in

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
>   resource
>   'https://warm-tundra-19548.herokuapp.com/assets/shopify_app/request_storage_access-5a556c57b51c57f00d9d6a2ba007f3172739bab34cc2f647a93e792348e8798d.js'
>   with computed SHA-256 integrity
>   '0lJjndtl8qUdAHc8U0DNkSIqNg4Nx2/QjfsZIycjNoU

Can you please help me with resolving this issue.

Comment: I'm having same issue, found any work around?

Comment: Hello @Marslan, you can downgrade sprockets version from "4.0.0" to "3.7.0" if you are using rails version greater than 6.

Answer (score 0):

this is kind of assets related issue , here try this

in assets.rb change

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

to

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = ''
```

and then try.

this works for me ! , good luck

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we had this exact error for many customers but we couldn't reproduce it on our own systems and it wasn't impacting all users. We purged the cache on our Cloudflare CDN and set up a rule in Cloudflare to bypass Shopify app gem .js and we're back in business. It seems like it was doing more than just caching and causing the integrity check to fail for some users but not all.